# Graphing function with asymptotes at y=0,1

Tags: graphing-functions, elementary-functions

[image: my picture]
Hi everyone. I'm searching for a formula to describe the above function piecewise. I've tried using things like translations of $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$. $1/x$ gives a nice asymptotic behavior, but I'm not sure how to neutralize the side of it to the left of the $x$-axis. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the unit step function?

Comment: Yes, anything is allowed. This is not an exercise for a course. Basically, I'm trying to find an open function from the real line to [0,1] (with the subspace topology), and I think this does the trick. I'm just having trouble describing its graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $1/x$ is what you want, since it goes asymptotically to zero, not to one (and it is negative when $x$ is negative, not positive like you want). How about a scaled version of the arctangent on the right side (which constant would you use to scale it?), $-1/x$ on the left, and linear function in between?

Another possibility for the function on the right is $x/(x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you both! The scaling constant would probably be 1/1.5.

Comment: I think it should involve $\pi$, right, since the asymptote of arctangent involves $\pi$...

Answer (score 1):

[One possibility is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7B-1%2Fx%2C+x+%3C+-1%7D%2C+%7B+-+x%2C-1%3C+x+%3C+0%7D%2C%7Btanh%28x%29%2Cx%3E0%7D%7D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+7%7D%5D):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}\\
-\frac{1}{x}&\text{if}\, x\leq-1\\
-x&\text{if}\, -1\leq x\leq0\\
\tanh(x)&\text{if}\, x\geq0\\
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: I think he wants an asymptote at $0$ as $x\to -\infty$. Right?

Comment: yes, the function is to have an asymptote at 0 as $x \rightarrow -\infty$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(@Eric Auld) Do you mean $\pi$ as part of the argument for the arctan? (i'm interested). The above graph, $(2/3)arctan(x)$, looks to do the job... Is this incorrect?

Comment: The argument of the arctangent is fine the way it is. The above graph is actually incorrect, but the reason it looks right is that $2/3$ is quite close to the right constant! You want the graph to have a horizontal asymptote at 1. Where does arctangent have a horizontal asymptote?

Comment: It looks like it has one at $y = \pi / 2$, so i might want to use $\frac{2}{\pi}arctan(x)$